# getQuantityString returns wrong string with 0 value

Tags: android, android-resources

In an android app, I have the following string resources:

```
<plurals name="test">
   <item quantity="zero">"I have 0 item"</item>
   <item quantity="one">"I have 1 item"</item>
   <item quantity="other">"I have several items"</item>
</plurals>
```

And the following line of code:

```
String text = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test, 0)
```

which I would expect to return

> I have 0 item

But it actually returns

> I have 1 item

Why ?

Comment: see this issues http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8287

Comment: i have not downvote your question someone else downvote here. i have just give you a link which is maybe helpful  for solving your issue. anyway +1vote

Comment: I believe it works as expected. [Tor Norbye about Quantity Strings](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/VYcxa1jUGNo)

Comment: @Sufian believe in what? zero is zero

Comment: @user924 zero is zero, true. But if the system doesn't support "zero" for the locale, then just don't use it. I recall in case of English the system looks for "one" and "other" (e.g 0 items, 1 item, two items, etc). Should it be in the docs? Sure. Is the implementation wrong? No because you aren't using it correctly. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36917255#comment3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quantity Strings are broken on some Plattforms and phones as the [issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8287) and this discussion ["Should Plurals and Quantity Strings be used"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/xz5JDBJvAVA) points out. It depends on many factors which you cannot control (i.e. localization on the phone).

One solution can be to take an external library like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/android-i18n-plurals/), which mimes the same functionallity.

Another solution is stated in the documentation of plurals in android. Avoid using it and use "quantity-neutral" formulations like "Books: 1"

Comment: I thinkg that for now I'll just declare 2 string resources and pick the right one programatically

Comment: It's inconvenient, but as the Google Engineer pointed out in the Issue Tracker thread, this is the intended behavior. In English, you only need "one" and "other". The reason is that in English, you have "0 books", "1 book", and "2+ books". The conjugation for "zero" is the same as for "other". The reason the support exists, is that in some languages (the documentation lists Arabic as an example), "zero" is actually conjugated differently than plurals.

Comment: I believe it works as expected. [Tor Norbye about Quantity Strings](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/VYcxa1jUGNo)

Answer (score -5):

Change the code like this

```
String text = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.test, 0,0);
```

Comment: he doesn't have any `%` inside his quantity-strings, so for what reason he should insert FORMAT arguments? My guess is that this `feature` is still broken on many android phones