# Plurals not working as intended in android

Tags: android, string

I am using Plural strings provided by android-sdk. I have used following code to create a plural string:

```
 <plurals name="valuestr">
        <item quantity="zero">Choose a value.</item>
        <item quantity="one">%d unit.</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d units.</item>
    </plurals>
```

Java Code:

```
textView.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.valuestr,0,0));
```

When i am setting any value other than '0', this is working fine but when i am setting '0' it is showing **'0 unit.'**.

Please help!

**Update**

While searching more on the internet i came across a workaround which uses `java.text.MessageFormat` class:

```
<resources>
    <string name="item_shop">{0,choice,0#No items|1#One item|1&lt;{0} items}</string>
</resources>
```

Then, from the code all you have to do is the following:

```
String fmt = resources.getText(R.string.item_shop);
textView.setText(MessageFormat.format(fmt, amount));
```

You can read more about the format strings in the [javadocs for MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Comment: I would say it could be because you give it a formatArgs (the last 0), which may filter the plurals item to keep only those that require format args.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getQuantityString returns wrong string with 0 value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493011/getquantitystring-returns-wrong-string-with-0-value)

Answer (score 8):

A post was recently made on G+ about this. 
In short, it is because this will not pick the closest match by Integer ( 0 = zero), but because it will look for the best **grammatical** pick.

In your example, you use units. 
The correct usage would be; 
0 units
1 unit
2 units

Making, zero equal to pretty much any other quantity above 1

Read the full story here;
https://plus.google.com/116539451797396019960/posts/VYcxa1jUGNo

Comment: Quote from that thread: *Attempting to use `zero` to represent "no items" is a common pitfall. The trouble is also that ADT accepts it for languages for which it doesn't apply, for instance in English*

Answer (score 0):

Plurals defined in `<plurals>` sections of resource files are only to be used for a grammatical distinction with respect to singular/plural strings. You should not use them for other display logic, as you did. You should add some checking logic in your code instead.

The [Android developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals) clearly states this:

> Although historically called "quantity strings" (and still called that
>   in API), quantity strings should only be used for plurals. It would be
>   a mistake to use quantity strings to implement something like Gmail's
>   "Inbox" versus "Inbox (12)" when there are unread messages, for
>   example. It might seem convenient to use quantity strings instead of
>   an if statement, but it's important to note that some languages (such
>   as Chinese) don't make these grammatical distinctions at all, so
>   you'll always get the other string.

Your workaround - although working technically for your current implementation - does not appear like a clean solution either, in my opinion. Future business requirements may make it necessary to include more sophisticated logic than just displaying a different text. Or you may have a generic "no items selected" string in your resource file used at different locations, which could be reused only if you did not stick to your solution.

Generally, I would avoid using two different formatting techniques (String.format style formatter `%d` vs. MessageFormat style formatter `{0}` and pick one that you'd stick to in your whole application.